# Can I use Blender in a slow-motion video workflow?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am capturing video on my Canon 7D at 60fps with the intent to play it back in slow motion at 24fps. There are some Linux-based programs that will do this, but they are usually kind of buggy and I'm running Windows mostly now. How can I convert a 60fps video into a slower (2.5x longer) video at 24fps?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrX1sK_ZQqs&index=27&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can import the movie into Blender and then export it with a different framerate using this technique:

#### 1. **Import the movie**

Open up a "Video Sequence Editor" in a fresh Blender-scene. You should see something like  below:

[image: Movie-Import]

Click on Add > Movie and select the movie you want to convert. Make sure that the Blend-option (open the panel on the right with <kbd>N</kbd>) is set to Replace and Start Frame is 1 (see picture).

#### 2. **Export the movie**

Then you go to Render Settings:

[image: Video-export]

Make sure that you have selected the correct Resolution (the one of the video) and the slider is at 100%. Set the End Frame to the same as the Length of your video (seen in the picture 1 below Start Frame). Select the correct Frame Rate (24?) and the right format (I selected AVI Raw but it can be everything you like). Hit that Animation-button or Press <kbd>Strg+F12</kbd> to render.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Where is the Blend option located? I couldn't seem to find it. Nor did I seem to need it.

Comment: The blend option is in the vse properties sidebar (press N) the blend mode is only important when you have multiple strips in the vse. Also of note is that blender will adjust video strips to match the render settings but it doesn't re-time audio strips.

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to Output your video as a Image Sequence.

This is a simple walkthrough for your.

Start a new blend file.

- Go to Compositor (Shortcut)<kbd>Ctrl + Leftt Arrow</kbd>.
- Check Use Node.
- Delete the Render Layer.
- Add Movie Layer by going to INPUT>>MOVIE CLIP.
- Load up your movie.
- Add a Viewer Node.
- In Properties, Select Scene>>Output and set a Folder for your
  renders.
- In Properties, Scene >> Render Frames , set End Frame option to the
  length of your video.
- Also make sure, you are using the resolution which matches your video
  resolution.
- From Render Menu, Select Render Animation or press
  <kbd>Ctrl+f12</kbd>.

This will render out your video.

[image]

Now, Change Your View to Video Editing.

Since you are using the same blend file, you don't need to change the resolution or end frame length. However, change the Frame Rate to lower number (it is just beneath the End Frame below Fram Range Option.

- IN VSE press <kbd>Shift+A</kbd> and select image.
- Go to your Renders Folder.
- Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the render images.
- This puts the Sequence in your VSE.
- From Render Menu, Select Render Animation or press
  <kbd>Ctrl+f12</kbd>.

This will output your video to a desired fps with desired encoding at your chosen folder.